# Python - Implementing graphs and checking connections between edges and vertices

Tags: python, function, dictionary, graph, adjacency-list

How and what would be the most efficient way to implement a `hasConnection()` function for each of the following implementation of graphs. By this I mean a function that can check if there is a connection between two vertices e.g. `hasConnection(vertex1, vertex2)`

**Implementation A:** Represented by a dictionary of unsorted adjacency lists. E.g. if a graph has vertices A, B, C and D. A has a connection to B and D. This would be shown as

`{A:[D, B], B:[A], C:[], D:[A]}`

**Implementation B:** Represented by a dictionary containing dictionaries of sorted adjacency lists. The inner dictionaries have keys named 'adjacentVertices'. E.g. if a graph has vertices A, B, C and D. A has a connection to B and D. This would be shown as

`{A:{adjacentVertices:[B, D]}, B:{adjacentVertices:[A]}, C:{adjacentVertices:[]}, D:{adjacentVertices:[A]}}`

**Implementation C:** Represented by a dictionary containing dictionaries whose keys have value 'null'. The keys represent the adjacent vertices. E.g. if a graph has vertices A, B, C and D. A has a connection to B and D. This would be shown as

`{A:{B:null, D:null}, B:{A:null}, C:{}, D:{A:null}}`

Ultimately, what would the code need to be for each of the implementations and which would be the most efficient version of `hasConnection()`?

Comment: for "hasConnection" only the most efficient way is to have a set of pairs which are the connections.

Comment: Honestly I seem to have come to a block on it, whether I'm just not remembering something or knowing it correctly. All I'm thinking of is any differences between searching through dictionaries and lists and maybe a for loop but I could be completely off.

Comment: Indeed lejlot but it needs to be for each of the implementations rather than pairs though, sorry. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for the unsorted adjacency list, the contains-check (iterative) is `O(N)` where N is number of edges starting in v1:

```
graph = {A:[D, B], B:[A], C:[], D:[A]}
def has_connection(graph, v1, v2):
    return v2 in graph.get(v1, [])
```

Secondly, for the sorted adjacency list, the contains-check (binary search using [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html)) is `O(log N)` where N is number of edges starting in v1:

```
graph = {A: {'adjacentVertices': [B, D]}, B: {'adjacentVertices': [A]}, C: {'adjacentVertices': []}, D: {'adjacentVertices': [A]}}
import bisect
def has_connection(graph, v1, v2):
    vs = graph.get(v1, {}).get('adjacentVertices', [])
    try:
        return v2 == vs[bisect.bisect_left(vs, v2)]
    except IndexError:
        return False
```

Finally, for the adjacency dictionary, the contains-check (hash look-up) is `O(1)`:

```
graph = {A:{B:null, D:null}, B:{A:null}, C:{}, D:{A:null}}
def has_connection(graph, v1, v2):
    return v2 in graph.get(v1, {})
```

Hence, the third implementation is faster than the second which in turn is faster than the first. This only holds for sufficiently large graphs where the inherent advantage of the respective algorithm outweighs its implementational overhead.